# Can't push elements from an Ajax call to a globally-scoped array after it's done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a globally-declared array in my function that I want to push elements from an AJAX call to.

AJAX call:

```js
function getDatesFromAJAX() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/api/dates/1",
    success: function(dates) {},
    error: function(xhr) {
      alert("Request status: " + xhr.status + " Status text: " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
var dateArray = new Array();

    // populate dateArray
    $.when(getDatesFromAJAX().done(function(dates){
        $.each(dates, function (index, date) { 
            dateArray.push(date);
        });
        console.log("DATE ARRAY INSIDE FUNCTION: ", dateArray);
        console.log("DATE ARRAY LENGTH INSIDE FUNCTION: ", dateArray.length); // 2 (expected)
    }));
    console.log("DATE ARRAY OUTSIDE FUNCTION: ", dateArray);
    console.log("DATE ARRAY LENGTH OUTSIDE FUNCTION: ", dateArray.length); // 0
```

Although the dateArray outside of the function maybe contains *something*, it has no length so I can't iterate over it. I think it may not be populating properly due to the nature of AJAX calls, considering the line 'console.log("DATE ARRAY OUTSIDE FUNCTION: ", dateArray)' gets printed **before** the DATE ARRAY INSIDE FUNCTION lines.

[This is what the console shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot27z.png)

Comment: It's just as you guessed it. It will not wait for the AJAX call.

Comment: I thought $.when().done() was supposed to make the following code wait until the call finished?

Comment: No it won't block code in the synchronous execution.